# what path to use in an ajax call in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, path

I have to read a text file that is located inside

```
/mnt/sdcard/koinoxrista
```

directory of my android device.

What is the path I have to use inside

```
jQuery.get('--------path_to_file-------',function(data){...}
```

call in my app?

Comment: you mean using jQuery to load a file in Android sdcard?

Comment: No I have allready saved the text file inside the above dir and I want to read it from my app

Answer (score 0):

The same path you would use to open the file in a browser. (Minus the domain if you want a relative path). If you can't open it in a browser it is not accessible over the internet and you'll have to move it to a directory that *is* accessible over the internet (typically somewhere in your web server's public directory.